# Is there a way to encrypt/decrypt or obfuscate/deobfuscate data passed to Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Does Google Tag Manager come with some possibility to decrypt encrypted (or at least obfuscate/deobfuscate to make it unreadable for human eye) information sent through `dataLayer`?

I'd like to encrypt certain information - such as € figures or unique identifiers in the page Javascript, and then decrypt these at Google Tag Manager before sending the values to Google Analytics.

I'm looking for something like the following at the page itself:

```
window.dataLayer.push({
    encryptedValue: encrypt(value, password)      
})
```

And at the Google Tag Manager creating an encrypted value (for example with custom JavaScript):

```
decryptedValue = decryption_function(encryptedValue, password)
```

Comment: The problem is, GTM is JS, so any decryption algorithms you have will also be exposed to the client, so someone can just look at your GTM code and find out.

Comment: Yes, that's a fair point. So probably "encryption" is not the correct term here - maybe obfuscation describes more what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, what you would do is create two variables. A Data Layer Variable  and a Custom Javascript variable in GTM.

**The data layer variable**
This will be where your "encrypted" value is stored. In this example, I've named it "myEncVar" for the datalayer and "EncVar" in GTM (just to keep things confusing), you would send this to the datalayer via `datalayer.push({myEncVar: [value]});`
[image]

**The custom javascript variable**
This variable will be where you store your "decryption" algorithm. Essentially, since you have already captured the encrypted value in a GTM variable through the datalayer, now you can reference it in the custom javascript. The setup will be something like this:
[image]

The value out of "decVar" will be what you want to use for the "decrypted" value.

Comment: Also noticed that you wanted to pass a "password" value, if that password value is constant/same for all values, then you can just store it in the custom javascript variable in GTM, otherwise, you can create another datalayer variable that will take in the password. Note, if you go with the datalayer route, you have to make sure you work with the value/password before the next datalayer push, otherwise, it could be mismatched/overitten.

Answer (score 1):

No matter if you call it encryption or obfuscation, everything somebody needs to decrypt or de-obfuscate will be right in the GTM code. So this might prevent someone from taking a casual look, but everyone who has five minutes to spare will still get at the information. That might be enough for you.

If not, you might look into data import instead. Instead of an encrypted value you store an anonymous key field that can be matched to a corresponding key in a data import file. Be aware that in the free analytics version you need to upload your data before you can match hit data to it, so if the values change fast that might not work for you (with GA360 you can import so that the import is applied retroactively).

Comment: And I guess Google Analytics, for example, doesn't contain a feature to decrypt anything? That would solve the problem of having the decryption algorithm being visible.

Comment: Not in any convenient way, no. I am almost sure you could decode a simple substitution cypher with advanced filters and regexes, but that would require dozens of filters, and of course substitution cyphers are not safe to begin with.